# Subsetting an xts object containing logical values in the first column fails

Tags: r, xts

Can anyone explain me please what's happening in the R code below and why?

```
a <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2001-01-01'),'day')
b <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2002-01-01'),'day')
a <- as.xts(1:NROW(a),a)
b <- as.xts(1:NROW(b),b)

NROW(b[index(a)])
d <- b>100
NROW(d[index(a)])
d <- cbind(b>100,b>100)
NROW(d[index(a)])
d <- cbind(b>100,b)
NROW(d[index(a)])
d <- cbind(b,b>100)
NROW(d[index(a)])
d <- cbind(b,b)
NROW(d[index(a)])
```

For some reason subsetting an xts object with a vector of dates fails if the xts object stores logical values in the first column. I know that subsetting with a logical vector like

```
NROW(d[index(d) %in% index(a)])
```

works, I'm curious why using a vector with dates doesn't work.

Comment: This has been fixed in r790 on R-Forge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  The logical operators are dropping the `tzone` attribute from the index, which causes them to be slightly different.  For example, compare:

```
> attributes(.index(b))
$tzone
[1] "UTC"

$tclass
[1] "Date"

> attributes(.index(b-1))
$tzone
[1] "UTC"

$tclass
[1] "Date"

> attributes(.index(b>1))
$tzone
[1] ""

$tclass
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Thanks! as.POSIXct() seems to fix the problem.